# Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:gluster/ubuntu-glusterfs-3.5'

Tags: ppa, repository

I am runnning into problem adding a repository.

```
~# add-apt-repository ppa:gluster/ubuntu-glusterfs-3.5
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:gluster/ubuntu-glusterfs-3.5'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

Any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This PPA doesn't exist. Do you mean [ppa:gluster/glusterfs-3.5](https://launchpad.net/~gluster/+archive/ubuntu/glusterfs-3.5)?